# What type of transaction is this with multiple senders and which sender pays the fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, blockchain-explorer

What type of transaction is this https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/db9342a6924722818555e8ee30a3bf96d43aa2bdc66644f8ccb9b04a12bc2535 that has multiple senders and which of those senders pays the fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an ordinary transaction. There are many possible reasons for a transaction to have large numbers of inputs and outputs. Maybe a shopkeeper is using change to pay employees. Maybe an exchange is using up small coins to batch pay withdrawing customers. Maybe one of thousands of other situations applies.

It is not possible to identify who pays the fee, Bitcoin does not ever explicitly record who pays the fee.